# State Tax Error

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, payroll-taxes

I completed the paper work with my new employer to have state taxes deducted from my pay.  The employer enter the information into the ADP system and the ADP screens indicate that state taxes to be deducted.  When I received my w2 NO state taxes were deducted from by pay.  I contacted ADP and state this was a system error. Is ADP responsible for the state taxes?

Comment: What do you pay stubs show? Which state?

Comment: Did they take money out of your paycheck? If not, why do you think ADP would be responsible for paying your taxes?

Answer (score 6):

No, ADP is not responsible for paying your state taxes. If there was an error in your withholdings it's your responsibility to catch it (by looking at your paystubs) and correct it in future withholdings.  If it's an error in your W-2, then hopefully ADP will send you a corrected W-2.

If it ends up that the W-2 is correct and ADP did not withhold properly, you could *try* petitioning for a waiver of any underpayment penalty and/or interest due if you can show that they should have withheld state taxes based on the W-4 you submitted, but I do not know how willing the state is to make such an accommodation.

At best, you'll have to pay the tax that should have been withheld when you file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure employers are responsible for witholding state taxes, and ADP is acting as an agent for the employer.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes the employer actually withholds the tax but ADP (I presume) does the calculations based on W-4s. I don't think it's material to the question, though. The taxpayer is ultimately responsible.